# Oracle SSO (Passlogix) prevents Java Application from starting

Tags: windows, windows-registry, java

I have a Java application which uses a bundled Java runtime (it does NOT use a system installed version of Java).

- ✅ When I start the application using `java.exe -jar myapp.jar`, the application works just fine
- ⛔️ When I start the application using `javaw.exe -jar myapp.jar`, the application crashes

  - The application logs show a sudden stop, suggesting a hard-crash.

We've narrowed the crash down to the following registry key, which is used by **Oracle Enterprise Single Sign-On Client 11.1.2.3.2**.

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Passlogix\Extensions\AccessManager\JHO]
"JavaHostNames"="javaw.exe"
```

- When we remove or rename this `JavaHostNames` value, the application starts just fine.
- The crash is reproducible in the target environment on multiple machines
- Incase the information is helpful, there are other registry entries adjacent to `JavaHostNames`:

  ```ini
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Passlogix\Extensions\AccessManager\JHO]
  "Path64"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Passlogix\\v-GO SSO\\Helper\\Java\\ssojho64.dll"
  "Hook"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Passlogix\\v-GO SSO\\Helper\\Java\\jhohook.dll"
  "Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Passlogix\\v-GO SSO\\Helper\\Java\\ssojho.dll"
  "Hook64"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Passlogix\\v-GO SSO\\Helper\\Java\\jhohook64.dll"
  "JavaHostNames"="javaw.exe"
  ```

Digging around the internet does not show much but I was able to find this similar bug: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2791640_1.html [[mirror](https://github.com/qzind/tray/files/10270627/Java.Application.Fails.To.Start.With.ER.5._.When.ESSO.Logon.pdf)].  Unfortunately there is no public workaround or solution (logging in with an Oracle account didn't show any more information).

Question(s):

- How do organizations using Oracle SSO handle crashes with 3rd party Java applications?  Specifically, is there known environment workarounds for these to co-exist.
- What is the purpose of this `JavaHostNames` registry entry and why does it impact 3rd party Java applications?